# Not full text search on all mongodb fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I created a search index `db.getCollection('Module').createIndex({ "$**": "text" },{ name: "$**_text" })`

And I tried to search for part of the field, for example 10, as in `SQL Like '%%'`

I searched like this `db.getCollection('Module').find({$text: {$search: "/.*10.*/i"}})`

Tell me where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Do you have search index?

Comment: I only have a text index, I understand that it is used for searching. But my knowledge of mongo is not very good